# cowplot plot_grid scales down size of plots automatically

Tags: r, bookdown, cowplot

I am trying to render a pdf with a series of 25 plots arranged in 6 columns using `cowplot`'s function `plot_grid`.

I would like these to show up the same size that they would appear if I had only one row. For some reasons though the size of plots gets smaller as I add new rows. Is there a solution that I am not aware of? Below is the code with the two outcomes. Many thanks in advance

1 row only `plot_grid`:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plot_emmeans_N_L, plot_emmeans_N_L,
plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L,
plot_emmeans_N_L,  nrow = 1, ncol=6, align = "v")
```

Here how it looks:
[image]

Here is the 25 plots together in 5 rows with `plot_grid`:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plot_emmeans_N_L, plot_emmeans_N_L,
plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L,
plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L, plot_emmeans_N_L,
plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L,
plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L, plot_emmeans_N_L,
plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L, 
plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L, plot_emmeans_N_L,
plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L,
plot_emmeans_N_L,plot_emmeans_N_L, 
NULL,NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, nrow = 5, ncol=6, align = "v")
```

This instead comes out much smaller:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/49440858/4975218

Comment: You're right, Sorry I did not mention this but I am actually trying to render this to a .pdf document using Bookdown library, can I adapt either of these lines of code (I think both of them work with knitr in Markdown)?

`ggsave("yourfilename.pdf", height = 20, width = 20, device = "pdf")`

`save_plot("general.pdf", my_plot, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually my best solution was to use the patchwork library and  (banally) to add the chunks options `fig.height= x, fig.width= y` , this being the size of all of the plots together,as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634520/specify-height-and-width-of-ggplot-graph-in-rmarkdown-knitr-output#39634521)